# I want to create a SFTP server for multiple users and also create a pgp to encrypt the data

Tags: ssh2-sftp

i want Both ssh key and pgp keys how to create that explan me clearly

i think ssh key par is sufficient for sftp operations but the client askin for both ssh key pair and pgp keys how can i create and give it to theclient